# Present image in google maps in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using google maps in flutter.

I have JPG image file I want to present at a specific location with some specific width and length.

I do I accomplish that ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can:
1. Convert your image to Uint8List
2. Use fromBytes(Uint8List byteData) → BitmapDescriptor
Creates a BitmapDescriptor using an array of bytes that must be encoded as PNG.
in Marker icon.

you are all set!

Comment: But will the image changed according to the zoom ? I need it to increase / decrease according to the user zoom